# Mono Views rendering (errors?) numbers, in IIS is ok

Tags: c#, mono, servicestack, fastcgi-mono-server

I'm running a .NET on mono 2.10, developed with ServiceStack 3.9.55

When i run the website with IIS Express everything is OK, but with mono 2.10 and fastcgi-server4 the page render extra numbers like 0 and f7e.

I've already tested this o Ubuntu 12, Debian 6 and 7 and the same numbers are displayed.

See it here. http://aaviseu.guilhermecardoso.pt/home

What you think it may be?

UPDATE: This error only appears on 2.10 and it's related with chuncked encoding (on 2x). I don't know when this was fixed, but i'm using 3.2.7 without any problem

Comment: Besides nginx, can you test with apache?

Comment: I can't get razor to render views with mod mono (i've copied the same assemblies that i'm testing on nginx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're having a similar problem as me: 
[Binary data corrupted when hosting ServiceStack in Mono + FastCGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755322/binary-data-corrupted-when-hosting-servicestack-in-mono-fastcgi) - f7e is probably the data size (3966 bytes).

**Edit:**

This is due to chunked transfers (introduced in HTTP 1.1). I was able to work around my problem by forcing the request to use HTTP 1.0.

On my question knocte suggested a patch to mono that might fix your problem:

Patch: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/attachment.cgi?id=3356

File: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpResponse.cs

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not skilled enough to do it (yet!). 
This is what i've done: forked mono projected, made that patch on branch 2.10 in my repo (from github i've edit that file) and i've installed mono from my git repo selecting the branch 2.10. I still get the numbers on response but i'm not sure if i've sucefully installed the modified fork.
Do you know how i should do this properly?

Comment: That's what I would do. To debug it just add a log message temporarily

`if (worker_request.GetHttpVersion () == "HTTP/1.1") {
 string GatewayIface = context.Request.ServerVariables["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"];
 use_chunked = (GatewayIface == null || !GatewayIface.StartsWith("CGI"));
 
 using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("/tmp/my_mono_fork.log"))
  w.WriteLine("use_chunked={0} GatewayIface={1}", use_chunked, GatewayIface);
}
else
 use_chunked = false;`