# What is a tested combination of versions of Mono+mod_mono for running ServiceStack in Apache on Debian?

Tags: apache, razor, mono, servicestack, mod-mono

I am trying to deploy a ServiceStack solution to Apache running on Debian with mod_mono.

I am running into problems like this one: [HttpCompileException: "External exception" when trying to access razor view in ServiceStack hosted on Apache+mod_mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118595/httpcompileexception-external-exception-when-trying-to-access-razor-view-in-s)

The project uses Razor (which is the source of the biggest problem I ran into at the moment, see linked question).

**What is a tested and recommended combination of versions of Mono+mod_mono (+XSP?) for running ServiceStack in Apache on Debian?**